# Having problems with background image using CSS

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, firefox, background

I'm having issues with trying to add a background image to my website,
The background showes up in Firefox but I have to reload the page 2 time before I can see it :/ and on Chrome, it does not show up at all :/

Here is my code:

```
html {
    /*-------------------------- Fond De Pages --------------------------*/
    --blue-back: fixed url("/medias/images/blue_back.jpg");
    --christmas-back: fixed url("/medias/images/christmas_back.jpg");
    --mlg-back:  fixed url("/medias/images/mlg.png");
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    background: var(--christmas-back); /* Changer le fond ICI */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display:inline-block;
}

body {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and here is my website so you can see what happens:

Comment: http://whatsthegeek.dtdns.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: In some versions of chrome, CSS variables are not supported !

I've had to directly enter the url of the background image and no, it's working properly !